# Accessing duplicates in objects in the same array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array with multiple objects

```
arr = [
{name: 'xyz',
age: 13,
},

{name: 'abc',
age: 15,
},

{name: 'abc',
age: 15,
}]
```

how do I find the duplicate in this array and remove the object that is duplicated in the array? They are all in one array.

Apologies. I just realized what I am trying to do is, remove the object entirely if there's a duplicate in one key... so if the age is similar, I will remove object name "def". Is this possible?

```
arr = [
{name: 'xyz',
entry: 1,
age: 13,
},

{name: 'abc',
entry: 2,
age: 15,
},

{name: 'def',
age: 13,
entry: 3
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by the following steps:

- transform each element into an object that is key-sorted, this will make objects consistent in terms of key-value pairs order, which will help us in the next step
- map the array into JSON-stringified value, and store it into a `Set()`, which would help us store only unique stringified objects
- turn the `Set()` back into array
- map the array back into objects by `JSON.parse()` each element

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "xyz", age: 13 },
  { age: 15, name: "abc" },
  { name: "abc", age: 15 },
]

const sortKeys = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).sort((keyValuePairA, keyValuePairB) =>
      keyValuePairA[0].localeCompare(keyValuePairB[0])
    )
  )

const res = Array.from(
  arr
    .map(sortKeys)
    .map(el => JSON.stringify(el))
    .reduce((set, el) => set.add(el), new Set())
).map(el => JSON.parse(el))

console.log(res)
```

### References

[Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

[Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

[Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Comment: is there a way to compare with the "name" key in the object? Can we call the name key and do name1 = name2, remove name1?